# aspnetboilerplate: removing x-frame-options headers

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

[image]

in my aspnetboilerplate based site,
how do I remove `X-Frame-Options:   SAMEORIGIN` header from asp.net core response.

**what I have tried**

1.

```
        string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://www.example.org/",
                                    "https://www.example.org/");
            });
        });

 app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

2. also tried adding this in startup

   `services.AddAntiforgery(x => x.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);`
3. adding in web.config `<remove name="X-Frame-Options"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize abp framework as follows:

```
        app.UseAbp(options =>
        {
            options.UseSecurityHeaders = false;
        }); // Initializes ABP framework.
```